# Is there any caching Proxy available for Golang Dependencies as it is existing e.g. for NPM (NodesJS)?

Tags: go, dependencies, nexus, dependency-management, godeps

For NodeJS i can use an internal Nexus Server as central Repository.
This Server can work in addition as Proxy, so if the Package is not known locally, it goes to registry.npmjs.com or whatever is configured and loads the package from there.

Than this package will be stored in the Nexus with all related meta info like Version etc. With that we are always build able, even when the Owner deletes the public repo or a new Version has breaking changes .
In addition we can make reviews and allow only reviewed main packages etc.

Is there something equal available for Go?

Comment: Go doesn't have a centralized registry, so this doesn't really apply. With the upcoming module feature Go will cache repositories automatically. You can deploy any caching HTTP proxy you like, of course. http_proxy works as expected.

Comment: And even if that wasn't the case... *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: I know that there is no central repo, but even without, an company wide central repo service could be established via the proxy functionality.
Question is only: do you know such a tool for go like it is existing for many other languages like Java, .Net, NodeJS, ...?

Comment: Not yet. And Go dependency management is still in flux anyway. Whatever the final solution ends up being, it may support this eventually, but don't count on anything like it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some projects which try to solve the mentioned issue by acting as central storage and proxy for dependencies.

Most promesing are project Athens and Artifactory 5.11.

Project Athens can work with go dep

- https://github.com/gomods/athens/
- https://docs.gomods.io/faq/

Artifactory 5.11 needs jfrog cli instead of go dep

- https://jfrog.com/blog/goproxy-artifactory-go-registries/